# Link to podcast 400's transcript is broken

Tags: support, status-completed, blog, podcast

[Podcast 400](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/14/podcast-400-an-oral-history-of-stack-overflow-told-by-its-founding-team/) of the SO podcast  links to https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/an-oral-history-of-stack-overflow-from-its-first-four-employees/transcript . It should link to https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/14/podcast-400-an-oral-history-of-stack-overflow-told-by-its-founding-team/

Also it calls Geoff Dalgas Jeff Valgus I think

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The podcast post appears to be linked to the correct transcript now. Thank you for reporting.

Comment: XD. Conditionally resolved. If someone can correct the transcript to fix Geoff's name that would be excellent... that's bothering me more than it should, knowing the horrible state of machine transcription